# webpack-loader generated chunk gives 404 error from webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, web-worker

This is (an abbreviation of) my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const src = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const dst = path.resolve(__dirname, 'www');
const node_modules = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

module.exports = {
  module: {
      rules: [
          {
              test: /\.worker\.js$/,
              use: {
                  loader: 'worker-loader',
                  options: {
                      inline: false,
                      fallback: false,
                      name: '.' + path.sep + 'js' + path.sep + '[name].js'
                  }
              }
          },
          {
              test: /\.js$/,
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                  presets: ['es2017', 'es2016', 'es2015' ],
              }
          },
          {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              use: [{ loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader",
                      options: {
                          url: false
                      }},
                    { loader: "sass-loader" }]
          }
      ]
  },
  context: src,
  entry: {
    app: '.' + path.sep + 'js' + path.sep + 'app.js',
    styles: '.' + path.sep + 'styles' + path.sep + 'styles.scss'
  },
  output: {
    path: dst,
    filename: '.' + path.sep + 'js' + path.sep + '[name].js'
  }
};
```

I refer to a worker like this:

```
import StationWorker from './stations.worker.js';
...
        this.stationWorker = new WorkerConnection (new StationWorker ());
```

When I run my app using `node_modules\.bin\webpack-dev-server -d --progress --content-base platforms\browser\www --port 8081`, the output tells me that it has generated `.\js\stations.worker.js`:

```
         Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
   .\js\app.js  15.2 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  app
.\js\styles.js  1.07 MB       1  [emitted]  [big]  styles
...
Child worker:
    chunk    {0} .\js\stations.worker.js (main) 2.55 MB [entry] [rendered]
```

However, when my code attempts to load this generated file, I get a 404 error from the server.  I've tried various combinations of not including the path in the name, using default settings, and using `publicPath` to specify the path, all of which have had the same effect.

How do I get `worker-loader` to generate code that `webpack-dev-server` is able to serve?